# Dynamically serving different mobile HTML content and having mobile site too

Tags: google-search, mobile

We are dynamically serving a HTML page that is appropriate for mobile users. It has the same URL but different HTML source code.  We also have a separate mobile site.

Is there any problem for Google SEO with two different sites that both do mobile?

Comment: Why do you maintain both?   Wouldn't it make sense to redirect one to the other, just in terms how much work you have to do for site maintenance?

Comment: See my answer to this here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65203/what-is-googles-policy-about-separate-content-on-same-urls-in-mobile-and-deskto/65221#65221

Answer (score 1):

Google have a guide here as to how they handle adaptive and responsive design, including "Dynamically serving different HTML on the same URL":

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details

In your case, it sounds like you just need to add `Vary: User-Agent` to your header.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there might be problems due to Google penalizing your site because you are showing different content for different clients on the same URL. While the chance is not high, there is still a possibility of this. If you want to avoid it, I would suggest redirecting mobile users to a mobile site instead.

Comment: Google allows you to change your content based on device, as long as you show the appropriate content to each version of Googlebot.  See: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/redirects